# Make windows 11 task bar like windows 10?

Tags: windows-11, taskbar

What's the easiest cheapest way to make the Windows 11 taskbar act more like the Windows 10 taskbar.

For example: being able to pin a file (something.doc etc) to the Taskbar or Start Menu.

I'm open to 3rd party apps.

Comment: Windows 11 is not Windows 10 and what you want is not natively possible. Try one of the 3rd party start button apps.

Comment: Stardock [Start11](https://www.stardock.com/products/start11/)

Answer (score 1):

This is free and open-source :
[RetroBar](https://github.com/dremin/RetroBar),
described as:

> Pining for simpler times? RetroBar teleports you back in time by replacing your modern Windows taskbar with the classic Windows 95, 98, Me, 2000, XP, or Vista style.

It does taskbars that are before Windows 10, but this may be enough.

Answer (score 0):

Here's another app that costs $7 but looks pretty good.

https://www.xda-developers.com/start11-v2-review/

(1) I am not affiliated with this company, nor do I earn anything if you buy it. I've not bought it myself.

Comment: I think an edit saying you are not affiliated with this product and do not earn comission might be useful, here.